# Excel: Optimal way of auto populating based on selected criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm hoping to find a more efficient way to extract/calculate in cells based off of numerous categories/inputs. I currently have an Excel doc in which I average demographic variables (population, median income, etc.) based upon property locations which fit the criteria (region, sub-region, state, city, market type). For example, if I were to select Region: Midwest and Market Type: Suburban, then only suburban Midwest properties will be included in the calculation. Due to the varying levels of specificity, there are many possible "combinations."

As it stands, I'm utilizing a large `IF` and `AVERAGEIF` function to work through that (simplified example: `IF(AND(Region = Midwest, Market Type = Suburban)`, `AVERAGEIFS(*based on matching data table values to the fixed criteria cells on presentation sheet*)`. Is there a more effective method to perform this? It is manually intensive, so inherently not scalable. If a new category were to be added, the current method would require a great deal of writing more combinations. Attached is a photo link to help provide context. Thank you.

Lookup Categories and Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the IF inside the AverageIfs:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(ValueToBeAveragedColumn,DataRegionColumn,IF(REGION="All","*",REGION),...)
```

Repeat the `column,IF(...)` combo for all 5 criteria.

This will now use the value in the cell unless it is `All` then it will return all by using the `*` wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for your input. That would certainly compact the function a bit, but it would still require typing out all potential combos. I'm hoping there is a work-around to the manual typing of category combinations. I'm open to tools outside of Excel. I understand though that this is a specific request, so there might not be more efficient means of production. Just now noticing the "*" wildcard, that could go a long way in simplifying things. I'll try that. Thanks again.

Comment: no it would not.  for example if region is `Midwest` then it would use that as the criteria. Or anything else that is put in there.  If it is `All` it uses the `*` wildcard, otherwise it uses what is in the cell.  If on one of the cells has a value different than `All` it will average only on that criteria as the others will return all.

Comment: Oh wow, no kidding. I see how that works now. That is incredibly useful. Thank you so much!